# Polymer Custom elements dataset is empty in Firefox

Tags: polymer, web-component, custom-element

I have the impression that Firefox is "clearing" the `data-*` attributes on custom elements.

See the script below works in Chrome with native Web Components support, but in Firefox, it seems that once my click event handler is run, the dataset is empty.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var popups = document.querySelectorAll('iron-image[data-popup]');
    for (var i=0; i < popups.length; i++) {
        var img = popups[i];
        console.log(img.dataset.popup);   // <--- this works

        img.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
            var app = document.querySelector('sh-app');
            app.showPopup(ev.target.dataset.popup);  // <-- This fails, dataset is empty
        });
    }
});
```

*Side Note*: I have also tried the `WebComponentsReady` event, but it doesn't get fired at all for some reason.

Has anyone run into this issue before and understand the cause?
Is this a bug in Polymer (`<iron-image>` in this case), the Web Components polyfills, or Firefox's implementation thereof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Event retargeting](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/events#retargeting)

Basically, you have to wrap the event using `Polymer.dom` to normalize it.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var popups = document.querySelectorAll('iron-image[data-popup]');
    for (var i=0; i < popups.length; i++) {
        var img = popups[i];
        console.log(img.dataset.popup);   // <--- this works

        img.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
            var app = document.querySelector('sh-app');
            var event = Polymer.dom(ev); // you wrap the event using Polymer.dom
            app.showPopup(event.localTarget.dataset.popup);  // instead of target you should use localTarget
       });
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! That works perfectly. I missed that part in the docs, probably only ever read it once, and forgot about it thinking: "I'll probably never need that", until I did ;)

Comment: @andre Side note btw, you should use forEach here instead of a regular for loop. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures#Creating_closures_in_loops_A_common_mistake